# Calling a number without showing number on the screen

Tags: android

In my application I want to call a number with the user's permission but the user will never know the number.  Maybe I can show 012345679 instead of the real number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, and would be a feature ripe for abuse.  Imagine a malicious app that dialed 1-900 numbers unbeknownst to the user.

My guess is the dialer application will always dispay the real number.

Comment: But if caller is a private number its number never shows.Can't i do like that?

Comment: The only thing what i want to do is that caller call a number but he never know what the number is.Also i can block screen light and when call ended i can delete the latest call.How can i do this?

Comment: @user1068377: That's an INCOMING call whose origin is blocked by the carrier (by adding the *67 prefix).

Answer (score 3):

For obvious security reasons, this is not possible.

Comment: The only thing what i want to do is that caller call a number but he never know what the number is.Also i can block screen light and when call ended i can delete the latest call.How can i do this?

Comment: @droidman - yes, but the only think someone else wants is to call a different number that will charge the user in $$$.

Comment: I want to create a different app.In my app people can create codes for their numbers and give this code to another person.If this person have this app he can call via this code without knowing the real number.With that caller can't know the real number.After some time code will be dead so it won't work.

Comment: Again, this is not possible, because others may use it for bad things.